# Why do the y axis values shift up from real point in line chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I drew a line chart using D3.js. It was nicely drown but with a little problem. The problem is , the values in y axis are not shown in corresponding point. The shape of the line is also correct. But it shifted up from the corresponding point. Here is My code and where did I do a wrong thing?

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var dataset = [
  {x: 0, y: true},
  {x: 1, y: true},
  {x: 2, y: false},
  {x: 3, y: true},
  {x: 4, y: true},
  {x: 5, y: true},
  {x: 6, y: true},
  
];

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.x; })])
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0,height]);
    
/*var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);
*/
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);
    


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);
    
yScale.domain(dataset.map(function(d) {return d.y;} ));        

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)

  svg.append("path")
      .data([dataset])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

```css
.axis path,
  .axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
  }

  .line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  .tick text{
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Line Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your any advice to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One change:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0,height]);
```

This should have been

```
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range([0,height]);
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/7ot58x0w/)

Hope this helps!